# Change of the sign of an integral of differential form

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I'm having troubles with understanding one thing. Consider an integral of some differential form $\omega$, say $n$-form, over some subset $V \subseteq R^n$, which is defined as follows:
$$\int_V f(x) \; dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx_n =
\int_V f(x) \;dx_1 dx_2 \ldots dx_n$$

For $\omega$ holds:
$$f(x) \; dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx_n = 
-f(x) \; dx_2 \wedge dx_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx_n$$

The thing that I don't understand why this doesn't imply that
$$\int_V f(x) \;dx_1 dx_2 \ldots dx_n =
- \int_V f(x) \;dx_2 dx_1 \ldots dx_n$$
which is obviously wrong, however.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is an artifact of the terrible notation of $\int (\cdot) dx$ which seems to imply things it doesn't do. Given a differential form $\omega= fdx_1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx_n$ on $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open set, we define
$$\int_{\Omega} \omega:=\int_{\Omega} f.$$
That's it. If you define the integral of differential forms like as above (which is what you are doing) and have a form $\eta$ and its representation is not $gdx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_n$ (with the $dx_i$ in the right order), then you "don't know" what is its integral (yet). You first "fix" the ordering, and then apply the definition above.

Comment: Thank you. Now it's clear.